# Can I create an instance of Abstract class?

Tags: flutter, abstract

I have a question about NetworkImage of Flutter.

```dart
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(''),
),
```

backgroundImage of CircleAvatar accept ImageProvider type. But ImageProvider class is an abstract class, so other subtype like AssetImage, FileImage, NetworkImage class object can be assigned to backgroundImage. That code doesn't have any problem.

```dart
abstract class NetworkImage extends ImageProvider<NetworkImage> {
  const factory NetworkImage(String url, { double scale, Map<String, String>? headers }) = network_image.NetworkImage;

  String get url;
  double get scale;

  Map<String, String>? get headers;

  @override
  ImageStreamCompleter load(NetworkImage key, DecoderCallback decode);

  @override
  ImageStreamCompleter loadBuffer(NetworkImage key, DecoderBufferCallback decode);
}
```

Here is my question. NetworkImage class is also an abstract class. I have learned that abstract class can't be instantiated, but NetworkImage can be instantiated although it is an abstract class.

How can it be done?

ImageProvider() can't be assigned to the backgroundImage because it's an abstract class so it can't be instantiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abstract class **can't** be initiated.

But you may ask if `NetworkImage` is `abstract` why we can use it in the `CircleAvatar` by providing the URL like in the example below

```
NetworkImage('url/to/image.png')
```

The answer is you are not initiating exact `NetworkImage` from `image_provider.dart` because you are calling a **factory** constructor that under the hood returns `network_image.NetworkImage` which is the constructor of `NetworkImage` class from `_network_image_io.dart`

```
const factory NetworkImage(String url, { double scale, Map<String, String>? headers }) = network_image.NetworkImage;
```

Comment: I googled _network_image_io.dart, I found the constructor of NetworkImage that you said. And it's not an abstract class. Thank you so much for your help!